# Linear Model requires variable as input plus output

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm new to coding, R and data science and have been picking up all of this mostly through online tutorials. I have written a shiny app where i am trying to implement a few things:

- Run a linear regression
- Run a Monte Carlo simulation
- Be dynamic in nature

So for this I used the `iris` data set. The purpose of the app is to allow a user to select input and output variables which will be passed on to a linear regression model. The user will then propose a distribution for his selected variables and use the linear model which was generated in a Monte Carlo simulation and output a histogram of the result.

However something doesn't seem right as I can only generate the histogram when I have the same variable selected under input and output and I cant seem to know why? What i mean by this is that for example I need to select `Species` under `Select input` and `output`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           wellPanel(
             sliderInput("sampleSize","Please Select Sample Size:",
                         min = 0,max = 5000,value = 1000,step = 100),
             uiOutput("invar"),
             uiOutput("outvar"),
             uiOutput("moC")))
    ),



  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("histogram")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  sorted <-  reactive({
    data <- iris[ ,c(input$inv)]
    data})

  output$invar<-renderUI({
    selectizeInput('invar',"Select Regression Input Variables", choices = names(iris), multiple = TRUE)
  })

  output$outvar<-renderUI({
    selectizeInput('outvar',"Select Regression Output Variable", choices = names(iris), multiple = FALSE)

  })




  sorted <-  reactive({
    iris[input$invar]
  })

  output$moC <- renderUI({
    numvar<- length(input$invar)

    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
      tagList(
        selectInput("inv",paste0("Please Select Probability Distribution of ", input$invar[i]),
                    choices = c("Normal","Uniform")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Normal'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmean","Please Select Input Variable Mean:",2),
                         textInput("invarpdfsd","Please Select Input Variable Standard Deviation", 0.02)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Uniform'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",1),
                         textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value", 5))


      )})})


  output$histogram <- renderPlot({
    n <- input$sampleSize
    numvar<- length(input$invar)
    SelectedVars <- input$invar
    vartopredict <- input$outvar
    fmla <- reformulate(SelectedVars, response = vartopredict)


    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
    if(input$invar[i]=="Normal"){

      invarpdfVec <- rnorm(n,mean = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmean),sd= as.numeric(input$invarpdfsd))
    }

    if(input$invar[i]=="Uniform"){

      invarpdfVec <- runif(n,min = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmin),max = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmax))
    }
    })


    MCtab <- iris[ , input$invar]
    pred.model=lm(fmla,MCtab)

    for (n in 1:input$sampleSize){
      h <- predict(pred.model,MCtab)
    }

    h<- hist(h,breaks=30,col="red",freq=F)
    # Define the quartiles for the Min, Max, P10, P50 and P90


  }

)
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use a better title.

Comment: @Masoud I had changed it but  it never updated it seems. Thanks for the comment, others would just down vote and move on

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are most likely running into is with the `MCtab` variable. Try

```
output$histogram <- renderPlot({
  #...
  MCtab <- iris[ , unique(c(SelectedVars, vartopredict)), drop=FALSE]
  #...
})
```

You need to make sure your data.frame as all the variables you are trying to use in the formula you are creating.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and for explaining what is most likely the issue. `MCtab` is supposed to hold not only the selected variables but also their respective probability distribution as defined by the user. That was my attempt at doing that and it doesn't seem to have taken the defined distribution on board. Do you know a way to do this? Once again thank you for your time.